# Split parent's remaining width space between child elements with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a parent `div` with relative a width (100%), with 2 child `div` in it. The child elements width are based on the content in them. Let's say `child1` has a content which makes `child1` width to the 20% of the parent's width. The `child2`'s content makes it 40%. So basically the parent has 40% remaining space.

What I would like to achieve is to split the remaining space between the child elements evenly (by increasing their width). So `child1` should be 20% + 40/2 = **40%** and `child2` should be 40% + 40/2 = **60%**.

The whole thing should based on the content of the child elements, so only relative units are ok. Is this something possible to achieve with pure CSS?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your relevant HTML? This seems easily solved by flex-box layout, so may I ask where you got stuck?

Comment: Don't think you can do that with flexbox or any other layout method. I think you will need JS to calculate the remaining width and then apply the appropriate calculation.

Comment: @DavidThomas My problem is that the child elements width are sometimes 13% and 36% of the parent's width, sometimes 67% and 8% etc. and I am not aware of a solution where the child element could be "self agnostic" with their widths so something like width = calc(child1 + ((100% - child1 - child2) / 2))

Comment: No, not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: @Hordon - why didnt you do it like you wrote in comments? It would work, I guess, if you write calc() to variables. So first you count the width and than you set it. 
...and also.. you know that ratio(?) 20 to 40 is not like 40% and 60%.. its more like 33,3% and 66,6% ...is it still ok for you?